# kafka to DB2 select query is not returning any result

Tags: apache-kafka, db2

```
const dbUrl = "DRIVER={DB2};".concat("DATABASE=").concat(database).concat("UID=").concat(uid).concat("PWD=").concat(dbpwd).concat("HOSTNAME=").concat(dbHostName).concat("port=").concat(port).concat(";Security=").concat(Security);

const ibmdb = require("ibm_db");

//open the connection with ibm_db
var Pool = require("ibm_db").Pool;
var pool = new Pool();
var con = pool.init(5, dbUrl);
// pool.setMaxPoolSize(1);
if (con !== true) {
  console.log("Exceeded maximum limit of 5 connections. Connection refused " + dbHostName + " failed ");
} else {
  console.log("DB connection pool initialization to " + dbHostName + " done successfully!");
}
const connectAndExecuteQuery = async (user_query, params = {}) => {
  console.log(query)
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    pool.open(dbUrl, function (err, conn) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Pool is open err");
        return reject("Error getting connection from pool");
      } else {
        try {
          conn.query(user_query, params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
              //Cleaning pool
              pool.close(function (a, b) {
              });
              return reject("Error from DB: " + err + ". Connection pool has been purged");

            } else {
              return resolve(data);
            }
          }.bind(this));
        } catch (ex) {
          return reject(ex);
        } finally {
          conn.close(function (err) {
            if (err) {
            } else {
            }
          });
        }

      }
    }.bind(this));

  });
}
processMessage(data,offset){
 let query = 
    `SELECT * FROM ` + schema + `.TableNAME as t WHERE t.column = '${value}'`;
   connectAndExecuteQuery(query).then((resultSet) => {
      console.log(resultSet)
      if (resultSet.length > 0) {}
});
}
//consumer.js
consumer.on('data', async function (data) {
  
    try {
     
      consumer.pause([topic]);
      await processMessage(data, data.offset);
      consumer.commit();
      consumer.resume([topic]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('data consuming error', error);
    }
  
});
```

**
using node-rdkafka library to work with producer & consumer
write a topic to producer and consumer will read from topic and proccess those record into DB2.am executing select query by calling processMessage() function but it not retuning result.
can we connect from  consumer to database directly?
could any one please help me with issue
**

Comment: Please, please, please. Fix the SQL Injection vulnerabilities in the code! Someone might copy-paste that. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you getting an error message in the console or just no result? In addition to the SQL Injection vulnerability @MarekPuchalski mentioned, you are calling ``processMessage()`` but your function definition misspells it as ``prosessMessage()``; that's likely to prevent good things from happening.

Comment: Am not getting any error . when i run the application its connecting to DB but when icall prosessMessage(); from consumer failing to  execute the queries